The last five Moves #2
Once again, here is another retrograde analysis puzzle! The task is simple:
Can you determine the last five (half-)moves that led to the position below?

Please provide your reasoning and a (sketch of a) proof game in your answer. Have fun! :)

Arghh I can’t get that knight to g5! Actually wait a minute!!

Here is a proof game

 Analysis board:
 1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Ng1 Ne4 3. Nf3 Nc5 4. Ng1 Nd3+ 5. exd3 Nc6 6. Be2 Nb8 7. Nc3 Nc6 8. a4 Nb8 9. Ra3 Nc6 10. Rb3 Nb8 11. Ne4 Nc6 12. Rb4 Nb8 13. Nc5 Nc6 14. Nb3 Nb8 15. Na1 Nc6 16. Bg4 Nb8 17. Be6 Nc6 18. Ba2 Nb8 19. Bb1 a5 20. Ke2 Nc6 21. Kf3 Nb8 22. Ke4 Nc6 23. Qg4 Nb8 24. Nf3 Nc6 25. Re1 Nb8 26. Kf4 Nc6 27. Re5 Nd4 28. Rb6 Rb8 29. Ra6 Nf5 30. Ree6 Nd4 31. Ra8 Nf5 32. Rea6 g6 33. Ne5 Bg7 34. Nf3 Bd4 35. Nh4 Ba7 36. Nf3 b6 37. Nd4 Bb7 38. Nf3 Bd5 39. Nd4 Ba2 40. b3 Kf8 41. Nf3 Kg7 42. Nh4 Kf6 43. Nf3 Ke6 44. Nh4 Qg8 45. Nf3 Qg7 46. Kg5 Qd4 47. Ne1 Rb7 48. Rg8 Rb8 49. Rg7 Ra8 50. Nf3 Bb8 51. Ra7 Qc4 52. Rb7 Ra6 53. Nh4 Ba7 54. Nf3 Ra8 55. Nh4 Qd4 56. Rb8 Qc3 57. Rh8 Qd4 58. Rgg8 Qg7 59. Re8 Qg8 60. Bb2 Qf8 61. Rg8 Kd5 62. Bh8 Ne3 63. Rg7 Qg8 64. Nf3 Kc5 65. Nd4 Kd5 66. Ne6 Kc6 67. Nf8 e6 68. Kf6 Nc4 69. Ke7 Bb8 70. Kd8 Ne3 71. Qg5 Nc4 72. Kc8 Ne3 73. Qe7 Nc4 74. Qd8 Ne3 75. Re7 Nc4 76. Qe8 Nd6+ 77. Kd8 Nc8 78. d4 Kb7 79. d5 Ba7 80. d6 Kb8 81. g3 Nxd6 82. g4 Ne4 83. g5 Nxg5

Here is the analysis this is in more or less the order any proof game needs to follow:
I noticed initially that two white pawns are missing however, only the black knight is missing and with the final configuration of the board any promotions can be ruled out as it would require the taking of two of the black pieces by any of the missing pawns and not just one… Also the black king had to have entered via the unprotected f6 or h6 somewhere down the line.

First thing to consider is that the two white rooks can only enter the black’s back rank via the a file. This requires an opening created by positioning the black pawn on a5.

The queenside rook then needs to escape via the a file and the kingside rook needs to escape via the e or g file. This is because the dark squared bishop has to be locked in until both the rooks infiltrate the black’s back rank. If it isn’t then that would necessitate the black bishop reaching a2 first but then that necessitates b6 which then would block the entry of the rooks.

Also the white knight and bishop needs to reach a1 before the dark squared bishop escapes for obvious reasons and so too does the black dark squared bishop need to reach a7 before the light squared bishop can escape. Only after the white bishop reaches its position on b1 can the black bishop reach a2. And then only after that can the white dark-squared bishop actually escape.

In order for the white rooks to then reach their respective positions, it requires the king and queen evacuate the back rank first…

Then with a little bit of maneuvering around after all of this we can reach this position on the top right. It becomes clear that the white bishop needs to reach its position before the white knight does.




The white king and queen could have already entered before the top right configuration is reached just to add. However, the final position of the white queen and rook needs to be placed after the top right configuration is reached otherwise either the white knight or bishop would be prevented from reaching their final positions.

Now the last part is interesting, most of the sequence from here has to more or less occur in this order to finish the game off (with the last 4 and a half moves has to occur exactly as stated however and the knight check at the start). This can only occur after the white rook and queen reach their final positions and bear in mind the white king has to be on c8 to allow for all this. The white king needs to infiltrate the back rank and reach c8 via an obstruction from the dark-squared bishop. It can be neither from the black king (black king has to enter second even if there was no rook to block) because that would prevent the white king reaching c8 and so disallow the final configuration of the rook on e7, queen e8 nor from the black knight, since in trying to allow the black king to re-enter, it would lead to a discovered attack on the white king which would be unable to be blocked or even have prevented beforehand. We now know it obviously can’t be from any of whites pieces because they would be pinned to the king and unable to reach their positions afterwards. After queen e8, the knight has to be positioned in a way to immediately check the king on d6, if it didn’t then the remaining white pawn moves would be insufficient. Since it would waste an unnecessary pawn move, at least, for it to reach c8. The  black king should also be placed on c6 or a7 to minimize the number of pawn moves in the end. The black king could not have been placed on b7 and knight on d6 in the first place because that would have prevented king c8. (Nd6+ 77. Kd8 Nc8 78. d4 Kb7 79. d5 Ba7 80. d6 Kb8 81. g3 Nxd6 82. g4 Ne4 83. g5 Nxg5):



Neither of the white knights could be used as a blocker for the white king as the bottom-left trapped white knight in the proof game would prevent the other white knight from reaching its position since the white dark square bishop has not escaped which would trap the white king by the opponents king and make it impossible for the white rook and queen to reach its position. For the same reason is why neither the white light squared bishop nor the black light squared bishop can be used. (Either on b8 or c8):

The white knight that is not trapped in the bottom left corner in the proof game being used would also not allow the final desired position:


The white queen and rooks would just obstruct the entry of the black king. So we have a scenario where we need two blockers for the white king to allow for the black king to re-infiltrate the back rank and reach its desired position and we can only therefore have the black dark squared bishop and the black knight. But which one is on b8 and which is on c8? well… then it has to be like bishop and knight respectively since the bishop cannot occupy a light square. This conveniently also allows the knight to then escape and consume both the pawns with sufficient white moves at hand which have to have been untaken before hand to allow for the final sequence of moves leading to the final configuration. This is also why the black knight had to have been taken on d2 to allow enough moves for white at the end whilst, at the same time, allowing an opening for the white pieces to escape and placing the pawn on the d file to allow it to reach d6 for a needed consumption by the black knight at the end.



The d-file pawn needs to go up to d6 first before the g pawn even moves to reach this position in order for there to be enough moves for the knight to reach g5. After this position is reached the g file pawn needs to move to reach g5 one step at a time and the knight needs to follow the path marked in red:



Nice! Looks like you figured it out :) I'm looking forward to your analysis

That was a long second :P

@ACB My brain was only functioning at 10% capacity after finding the proof game forgive me

@TimSeifert I have edited this to make this as comprehensive as I can muster… please let me know if I am wrong anywhere or am missing something important. Thanks. And as always great puzzle!

Well done, overall! Though, there are a couple of minor points: The black king coming from c6 in the final sequence is not necessary, a7 is possible if the white king entered from the right (this is inessential, of course). I am also a bit confused by everything following point 7. As you (pretty much) argued before, the white king had to be the last surviving white piece to move, so I feel that there could be a cleaner argument for why the sequence had to play out (essentially) only one way. Other than that, this is great! Thanks also for your nice feedback, I appreciate it :)
